# How to add multiple gradients with different directions CSS

Tags: css

This is the [design I'm trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2qKg.png) and [this is what mine looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2lyc.png). I'd like some help with making the gradient at the top as so far I can only make it a solid colour due to the fact that I'm already using a gradient for the background itself and I don't know how to combine different gradients together.

```css
.top-card {
  height: 230px;
  max-width: 295px;
  min-width: 150px;
  border-radius: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.instagram {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, hsl(228, 28%, 20%) 99%, hsl(37, 97%, 70%) 99%);
}
```

```html
<div class="top-card instagram">
  <div class="gradient">
  </div>
  <div class="name-container">
    <img src=images/icon-instagram.svg class="top-icon" alt="instagram">
    <p class="name">@realnathanf</p>
  </div>
  <h1 class="follower-number">11k</h1>
  <p class="follower-text">FOLLOWERS</p>
  <div class="increment-container-top">
    <img src="images/icon-up.svg" class="arrow" alt="arrow">
    <p class="increment-increase">1099 Today</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be slight change in your html structure, All you need to do I fill a parent container with "bright gradient" and in it's child container, fill the section with darker one. Please check the code snippet below for better understanding :

```css
.top-card {
  height: 230px;
  border-radius: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  }

  .gradient {
  max-width: 295px;
  min-width: 150px;
  background: rgb(248,197,117);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(248,197,117,1) 13%, rgba(214,79,148,1) 91%);
  border-radius:3%;
  }

  .instagram {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, hsl(228, 28%, 20%) 98%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0%) 2%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
  <div class="top-card instagram">
    <div class="name-container">
      <img src=images/icon-instagram.svg class="top-icon" alt="instagram">
      <p class="name">@realnathanf</p>
    </div>
    <h1 class="follower-number">11k</h1>
    <p class="follower-text">FOLLOWERS</p>
    <div class="increment-container-top">
      <img src="images/icon-up.svg" class="arrow" alt="arrow">
      <p class="increment-increase">1099 Today</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```